# Taxonomy-{taxnonomy}.php is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have just created a custom post type (portfolio) for a wordpress website. I also have added a Custom Taxonomy called (portfoliocategory).

I have created a archive page for my Custom Post Type (archive-portfolio) which is working properly, but I need help with Custom Taxonomy Template, I have created taxonomy-portfoliocategory.php but it is showing the default archive page and not showing the taxonomy page template!!

Comment: More information needed, e.g. URLs template code, the filename of your archive pages template that is showing, the difference between the two, etc

Comment: also your taxonomy registration code would be useful

Comment: Okay, I have created a custom post type which you can see here:
http://www.creativekhan.com/portfolio/

It is working properly with archive-portfolio.php template. Now I have created a custom taxonomy for the "portfolio" custom post type. which you can see here:
http://www.creativekhan.com/portfolio/category/psd-design/

The custom taxonomy name is "portfoliocategory" I have also created "taxonomy-portfoliocategory.php" file but it still show the default archive/category page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of further information this diagram should explain the template heirarchy system:

[image]

[click for bigger](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

Thus if we have a term 'example' then example.com/portfoliocategory/example will show portfolio posts using the template `template-portfoliocategory.php` and if that isn't found it willl use `taxonomy.php` and then `archive.php` and finally `index.php`

Comment: I have change the taxnomoy default slug to "portfolio/category"
http://www.creativekhan.com/portfolio/category/website-design

Comment: Here is my custom post type registration code:
http://pastebin.com/PB7YRBXR

Comment: ah that explains a lot!n You now have an invalid slug! Instead use the rewrite option to change the URL