# Custom taxonomy template not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I have created a custom post type named `property`, and a taxonomy named `city` is attached to this post type.  There are several cities (terms) like `toronto`, `taiwan`,`dhaka`.

I want to create a template which can show all the post under a city.  I have created file `taxonomy-city.php`, but it is not working  .

Here is my code for `taxonomy-city.php` file .

```
<?php
/*
 * Template name: City
*/
get_header();

?>
<div id="page_content">
        <div class="page-wrapper">

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="page_content_wrapper">

                <div id="careers_table">
                    <p class="content_text">asdsd</p>

                </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                            <div class="post">
                                <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'cmeasytheme'); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                    <?php endif; ?> 

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It shows everything, but doesn't print out anything inside the loop.

I have visited these link too , but none of them came to any help

- [taxonomy-taxonomy-php-is-not-working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65912/taxonomy-taxnonomy-php-is-not-working)
- [how-to_create-a-custom-template-for-a-custom-taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/how-to-create-a-custom-template-for-a-custom-taxonomy)
- [how-to-setup-a-custom-taxonomy-term-template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137687/how-to-setup-a-custom-taxonomy-term-template)

Comment: Is it possible your taxonomy is actually called cities, therefore the file should be taxonomy-cities.php? Also, did you register the taxonomy with public=true?

Comment: No , my taxonomy name is "city" and public = true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` file is an Archive Template and not a good name for a custom template. So if you want to proceed with a custom template, try naming the file with something like `template-cities.php` and call the file to a Page.

Otherwise, make a simple `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` archive template, and in your case `taxonomy-city.php` with code like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page_content">
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page_content_wrapper">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <div id="careers_table">
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <p class="content_text"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php // pagination code here ?>
                </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="post">
                    <h3><?php _e('No City Found', 'cmeasytheme'); ?></h3>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- .page_content_wrapper -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div> <!-- .page-wrapper -->
</div> <!-- .page_content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And in this way, NO NEED to make any page and call a page template.

#### Suggestions

Though the suggestions are not related to WordPress, but related to Good practice:

- Try naming you classes hyphen-separated (-), NOT underscore-separated (_). So class like `page_content_wrapper` would be `page-content-wrapper`.
- Avoid inline styles, and make a class instead. So the clearing div `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` can be something like `<div class="clearfix"></div>` and you can place `.clearfix{clear:both}` in your external CSS file.
- Use important commenting so that you can have trace of the closing divs etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . It helps me a lot. But the problem was something different ,  I  made a mistake when I created the "property" post type .  I made 'exclude_from_search' => true, , after changing it to false , now template is showing data

Comment: i have found tutorial related custom taxonomies which base on hierarchical and Non-hierarchical. Hope it will help you to solve your problem  https://www.wpblog.com/create-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/

Comment: will I able to relation with the product ?